# How many unique passwords are possible over alphabet of $62$ if order and repetition of characters don't matter?

Tags: combinatorics

> Let there be some computer system for storing passwords. The length of passwords must be between $3$ and $100$ characters inclusive and must include one small letter, one capital letter and one number. There're $62$ legal characters in the system (A-Z, a-z, 0-9). The order of the characters doesn't matter as well as whether the characters repeat. For example, $a1abb1$ and $ab1$ are considered to be the same passwords. How many different passwords are possible?

The exercise recommends using inclusion/exculsion principle but I don't see why it should be used here, maybe I'm missing something.

Because order doesn't matter as well as repetitions we just need to choose some characters out of $62$. Therefore the number of different possible passwords is:
$$
{61\choose1}+{62\choose 2}+\dots+{62\choose 62}=2^{62}-1
$$
Even though there's a restriction on password length it doesn't seem to matter in this problem because repetitions don't matter.

Comment: Your answer looks like it should be correct. But maybe the exercise recommends it as practice in using the IEP?

Comment: Im not sure whether your understanding of the exercise is correct. It doesn't seem to make much sense to simply count the subsets of 62 characters. This would be too trivial. Maybe you should be careful about "orders of characters don't matter". Is this the original exercise?

Comment: @S.M.Roch you were right, I overlooked that the passwords must contain at least one small letter, capital letter and digit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the exercise suggests to use inclusion exclusion, like Ross hinted at, you could instead just count all triples of sets $A_1\subseteq\{A,\dots,Z\}$, $A_2\subseteq\{a,\dots,z\}$, $A_3\subseteq\{0,\dots,9\}$ with $|A_i|\ge 1$ for $i=1,2,3$. You get
$$
(2^{26}-27)^2 (2^{10}-11) = 4562142751537972397.
$$

Answer (score 1):

You are correct for the total number of passwords without the restriction that you need at least one character of each type.  Now subtract the ones missing a type, but you have double subtracted the ones which are missing two types.  That is where inclusion/exclusion comes in.